# Braintree hosted fields with PaymentRequest API

Tags: braintree, pci-compliance, payment-request-api

I'm using braintree and their hosted fields solution to be applicable for the easiest to qualify PCI level of compliance - SAQ A.
Google recently announced their PaymentRequest API which provided a great user experience, however it makes available sensitive card details to my website's js, which will make me ineligible for SAQ A.

Is there a way to use PaymentRequest API with Hosted fields, or should I become SAQ A-EP to be able to take advantage of the new feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

[Braintree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/) does not officially support the [PaymentRequest API](https://w3c.github.io/browser-payment-api/) with [Braintree's Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/setup-and-integration/javascript/v3) at this time. This could change in the future.

Comment: how do we know that the which braintree payment integration method has been used, either "hosted field" or "braintree SDK custom integration" in appliation?